# Индексация только одной папки

Tags: seo, веб-программирование

Мне нужно, чтоб поисковые роботы проиндексировали только одну папку. Главную страницу сайта индексировать не надо.

Как мне можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно запретить все пути индексации в robots.txt, за исключением интересующей.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /folder0/
Disallow: /folder1/
...
Disallow: /folder9/
```

Comment: Вот если я так напишу:

    User-agent: *
    Allow: /path/st/
    Disallow: /
То индексирована будет только та директория и все?

Comment: Вполне возможно. Проверьте в инструментах вебмастера Google и Яндекс.